# Grabbing the most duplicated letter from a string

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates

What I want to get accomplished is an algorithm that finds the most duplicated letter from the entire list of strings. I'm new to Python so its taken me roughly two hours to get to this stage. The problem with my current code is that it returns every duplicated letter, when I'm only looking for the most duplicated letter. Additionally, I would like to know of a faster way that doesn't use two for loops.

Code:

```
rock_collections = ['aasdadwadasdadawwwwwwwwww', 'wasdawdasdasdAAdad', 'WaSdaWdasSwd', 'daWdAWdawd', 'QaWAWd', 'fAWAs', 'fAWDA']

seen = []
dupes = []

for words in rock_collections:
  for letter in words:
    if letter not in seen:
      seen.append(letter)
    else:
      dupes.append(letter)

print(dupes)
```

Comment: Have you learned about dictionaries and sets? Counters?

Comment: Are you trying to do this per-word or globally for the whole list?

Comment: The entire list and I haven't learned about sets or counters

Comment: How about dictionaries? Is this homework? Either way, you need to read some more about the available data structures.

Comment: It isnt homework, just a challenge my friend made that he wants me to complete. I'm just unsure what to look up. Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Look up dictionaries and sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the letter which appears the greatest number of times, I would recommend the following code:

```py
def get_popular(strings):
    full = ''.join(strings)
    unique = list(set(full))
    return max(
        list(zip(unique, map(full.count, unique))), key=lambda x: x[1]
    )


rock_collections = [
    'aasdadwadasdadawwwwwwwwww',
    'wasdawdasdasdAAdad',
    'WaSdaWdasSwd',
    'daWdAWdawd',
    'QaWAWd',
    'fAWAs',
    'fAWDA'
]
print(get_popular(rock_collections))  # ('d', 19)
```

Let me break down the code for you:

`full` contains each of the strings together with without any letters between them. `set(full)` produces a set, meaning that it contains every unique letter only **once**. `list(set(full))` makes this back into a list, meaning that it retains order when you iterate over the elements in the set.

`map(full.count, unique)` iterates over each of the unique letters and counts how many there are of them in the string. `zip(unique, ...)` puts those numbers with their respective letters. `key=lambda x: x[1]` is a way of saying, don't take the maximum value of the tuple, instead take the maximum value of the **second element** of the tuple (which is the number of times the letter appears). `max` finds the most common letter, using the aforementioned key.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What does lambda do? Also, I dont know what set does either.

Comment: Note: This is a `O(m * n)` solution (where `m` is unique letters, `n` is total letters), thanks to the use of `full.count` (which is `O(n)`, and called `m` times). For an input of largely unique values, that's `O(n²)`. Using a `dict` of any sort (with `collections.Counter` being the obvious subclass) would get the work down to `O(n)`.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! ShadowRanger has correctly pointed out that there are faster ways of doing this. If you expect to do this for a very large number of characters, his solution is preferable.